# Is it possible to have a kind of persistent Docker image for GitLab-CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-sphinx, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-build

Thanks to `GitLab` pages, I'm building a documentation with [`Sphinx-doc`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/). My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is the following:

```yaml
image: python:3.10.5-alpine3.16

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade pip
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade sphinx
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade sphinx_design
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade sphinxext-opengraph
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade sphinx_comments
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade furo
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade myst-parser
  - pip install --verbose --upgrade linkify-it-py
  - sphinx-build --version
  - sphinx-build source build
  - mv build/html public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

The problem is, even if only a single comma is changed in a single `Sphinx` (`.md`) source file (among the 1229 ones), `sphinx-build source build` (run by the `Docker` image) rebuilds all the (1229) HTML pages, and this takes too much time (about 10 minutes). By contrast, on my local machine, if only a single source file is changed, `sphinx-build source build` (run in the terminal, not using `Docker`) rebuilds only the single corresponding HTML page and this takes only a few seconds.

Is there a way, on `GitLab`, to deal with some “permanent” `Docker` image that would be aware that not all the HTML pages have to be rebuilt each time a commit happens?

[Here](https://gitlab.com/dbitouze/test-faq-fr/) is my repo.

Answer (score 2):

You can [cache the files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) created by the sphinx build process (by default, this is usually `_build`, but configurable in your settings).

```yaml
pages:
  cache:
    paths:
      - **/_build
      - **/build
      - **/.doctrees
  # ...
```

You may need to adjust the directories/files you want to cache, depending on plugins used and the settings in your `conf.py` file.

Then, in subsequent pipelines, the cache should speed up the build process similar to how it works on your local machine. But keep in mind, some additional time will be spent compressing/uploading/downloading/extracting the cached files.

You'll probably also need to use `cp` instead of `mv` in your script so that the cache is restored in the correct location (or accomplish this some other way).

---

If you're not sure of what files are needed for this, you can try using [`cache:untracked:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cacheuntracked) which will cache all files not tracked by git. Use with care.

```yaml
pages:
  dependencies: []  # avoid accidentally caching artifacts
  cache:
    untracked: true
  # ...
```

Comment: With your first suggestion, the commits for changes in source files don't trigger any build (any job). Am I missing something?

Comment: I was wrong, probably because I forgot to use `cp` instead of `mv` in my script: the commits for changes in source files now do trigger the build but I needed to wrap the strings in quotes, e.g. `"**/_build"` instead of just `**/_build`. But still all the HTML pages are rebuilt each time a commit happens. I also tried with the syntax used in [these examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html#common-use-cases-for-caches) but [it still fails](https://gitlab.com/dbitouze/test-faq-fr/-/jobs/4624153999) to regenerate HTML page only from the changed source files.